# How to convert mixed letters and numbers to letters letters only? C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to get a grasp on how to do this assignment but my experience is limited. The idea is that I have to call a text file that contains letters (lower and upper case) and numbers all mixed, no spaces, and convert it to lower case only.

I would appreciate help with the first part which is taking out any numbers from the text and leaving only letters.

Comment: You first have to show us what you've tried and where in that attempt you are struggling. Only then we might help you.

Comment: Try to break your problem into small modules and then do each module like an individual task. It will help you in understanding the problem and approaching its solution.

Find out the followings::
-> Create a char array with letters and numbers all mixed, try to convert that array in small letters and print to console.
-> How to open and read a file in buffer?
-> Do the first part for the file buffer.

Comment: Yes, working on setting it up, will get back when I have something to show. Thanks.

Comment: @Abhineet Please don't teach people new to C++ to use C-style strings when there is `std::string` in C++.

Comment: @FeiXiang: That comment just gave an idea on how to approach the given problem. I do agree with your statement though.

Comment: @FeiXiang my intro to C professor did a mix of C and C++ and to this day I'm confused about all those different syntax. I know there's Google but how would you explain the uses of C strings and std::string?

Comment: I don't think people should be taught things from C before they learn things in C++, such as C-style strings and manually managing dynamic arrays. It's like teaching someone how to use a computer by teaching them how to do everything from the command line first. Those things are confusing and easy to misuse, and you pretty much never use them when you are starting in C++. Did you already know C when you started in C++? I'm not an expert, but as far as I know, the use of C-style strings today is probably to deal with legacy code and special circumstances, C++ strings can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode only, since OP didn't post an attempt:

```
string data = ReadFileData();
for (char character : data)
{
    if (islower(character)) print (character);    // Or output to file, append to string, etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks, pseudo code actually helps me a lot to get the grasp... i started to code yesterday and had a clustefuck, had a mid semester mini meltdown

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in several ways. I am only giving you the full code so that you can learn. Try other approaches on your own.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");

    if(!fin)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file!";
        return -1;
    }

    char c;

    while(fin.get(c))
    {
        if((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ))
        {
            fout << c;
        }        
    }

    fout.close();
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use something like `isalpha()` instead of doing the character arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks @Seeker, I will play around with this one and try to formulate something more original according to my knowledge.